# where is user.config?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

in vb.net i am trying to save application settings but for USER but i cannot find the user.config file

when does this file get created?

i searched my entire hardrive. i also searched the entire project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know where it is (and it's different under XP and Vista)

All you need to do is

```
Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: it saves automatically anyway when the form is closed

Answer (score 3):

The user.config file is typically stored in their profile directory under the following [structure](http://dotnetproject.blogspot.com/2006/08/where-is-userconfig-file-located-in.html):

```
Profile Directory\Company Name\App Name_Evidence Type_Evidence Hash\Version\user.config
```

Have you checked there?

EDIT: Taken from the article to help cover ambiguity about the path descriptions:

> Profile Directory - is either the
>   roaming profile directory or the local
>   one. Settings are stored by default in
>   the local user.config file. To store a
>   setting in the roaming user.config
>   file, you need to mark the setting
>   with the
>   SettingsManageabilityAttribute with
>   SettingsManageability set to Roaming.
>
> Company Name - is typically the string
>   specified by the
>   AssemblyCompanyAttribute (with the
>   caveat that the string is escaped and
>   truncated as necessary, and if not
>   specified on the assembly, we have a
>   fallback procedure).
>
> App Name - is typically the string
>   specified by the
>   AssemblyProductAttribute (same caveats
>   as for company name).
>
> Evidence Type and Evidence Hash -
>   information derived from the app
>   domain evidence to provide proper app
>   domain and assembly isolation.
>
> Version - typically the version
>   specified in the
>   AssemblyVersionAttribute. This is
>   required to isolate different versions
>   of the app deployed side by side.

Comment: im sorry i dont understand where that is

Comment: A user's profile directory is usually located at C:\Documents and Settings\<username> (XP) or C:\Users\<username> (Vista)